# php str_replace array by array

Tags: php, arrays, replace

String replace two arrays replace only each array the 1st occurrence

```
$text = 'The Book has read by Dog and Cat then Book show Apple not Dog';
$array1 =array('1','2','3','4','5','6');
$array2=array('Book','Dog','Cat','Book','Apple','Dog');
echo str_replace($array2, $array1, $text);
```

the output has been

```
The 1 has read by 2 and 3 then 1 show 5 not 2
```

but need output

```
The 1 has read by 2 and 3 then 4 show 5 not 6
```

string replace array by array 4th and 6th cant be replaced it has repeated It must be 1st occurrence only replace possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately `str_replace` doesn't have a built-in option to limit the number of replacements. You can use `preg_replace` instead, as this function has as [4th parameter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) the limit of occurrences.

Your code needs to take into consideration that the strings to replace are now regex so you need to add a delimited (e.g. the `/`).

Working code below:

```
$text = 'The Book has read by Dog and Cat then Book show Apple not Dog';
$array1 = array('1','2','3','4','5','6');
$array2 = array('/Book/','/Dog/','/Cat/','/Book/','/Apple/','/Dog/');
echo preg_replace($array2, $array1, $text, 1);
```

The output is

```
The 1 has read by 2 and 3 then 4 show 5 not 6
```

Comment: It's simply a delimiter for the regular expression required by `preg_match`. If you've never worked with regular expressions you can search a lot of documentation about those and you can start here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

`str_replace`  expects the needles in the first parameter to be unique(in a way). Hence, it doesn't look out for second occurrence of `Book` because the moment it finds `Book`, it searches for it's replacement index in `array1` and returns the match right away.

To overcome this, you can:

- Split the actual sentence into tokens.
- Check for each token's value in `array2` using [`array_search`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php).
- This would return you the index. You replace the token value with the value
  at this index in `array1` and later on unset this index in both `array1` and `array2`.
- This way, we will be able to get new subsequent matches for repeating tokens as well.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$text = 'The Book has read by Dog and Cat then Book show Apple not Dog';
$array1 = array('1','2','3','4','5','6');
$array2 = array('Book','Dog','Cat','Book','Apple','Dog');

$tokens = explode(" ",$text);
foreach($tokens as &$token){
    $idx = array_search($token,$array2);
    if($idx !== false){ // if match is found.
        $token = $array1[ $idx ];
        unset($array2[ $idx ]);
        unset($array1[ $idx ]);
    }
}

echo implode(" ",$tokens);
```

Answer (score 0):

*Simple approach:*

- Use `explode(delimiter, string)` to turn the `$text` to an array `$output` and separator as space  and later loop over it.
- Use a var `$i` to keep track position of replaceable word.
- in foreach pass by reference `&` to be able to change.
- check if `$word` in `$array2` if So change with corresponding number in `$array1` and increment `$i`.
- Join the words back with `implode(glue, pieces)`.

```php
$text = 'The Book has read by Dog and Cat then Book show Apple not Dog';
$array1 = array('1','2','3','4','5','6');
$array2 = array('Book','Dog','Cat','Book','Apple','Dog');

$output = explode(' ', $text);
$i=0;
foreach ($output as &$word) {
    if(in_array($word, $array2)){
        $word = $array1[$i];
        $i++;
    }
}
```

```php
echo implode(' ', $output);
```

*Print:*

```
//The 1 has read by 2 and 3 then 4 show 5 not 6
```